# Convert "9am" string into DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I want convert a string as simple as `"9am"` into a DateTime. In this case, if today is 6/12/17, the desired result would be `2017-06-12 09:00:00`.

Likewise, `"5pm"` would be `2017-06-12 17:00:00`.

Comment: Which programming language? Use tags in your question to specify related subjects.

Comment: It's Visual Basic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use DateTime.Parse

```
Dim dateStr As String = "8pm"
Dim dateobject As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

While M.Mahdipour's answer is the simplest and functionally this may not matter, I would strongly advise adding the following:

```
DateTime finalDateObject = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateObject, DateTimeKind.Local)
```

I've seen several rather bizarre issues arise out of conflicting specifications in this regard. By adding this line, you formalize the type.